# Using macros to convert print statements

Tags: c, macros, format-specifiers

I have multiple uses of one type of debug statement in my code - say `DEBUG("abcd");` or `DEBUG("abc %d def", val)` which get translated and printed to a file.

Now, however I want to convert them all to a different type of logging which requires using a function with declaration like -

```
WRITE(char *string);
```

Usage: `WRITE(L"abcd")` etc..
Because the usage of this debug statement is huge, I am hoping to use macros to convert the same. Can this be done; also given that the `DEBUG` function used to take in format specifiers too?

Comment: the question is slightly confusing. Can you give us an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok
I need to convert my Debug() statements to Write() statements. Because the usage of Debug statements is huge; I am looking to use a macro to convert all in one go.
Debug() takes a string as input, with format specifiers too.
I am looking to be able to convert the same to a single string to be consumed by Write().
Also there is a unicode/ansi thing for which I need to use L"" in my Write function.

Trying something like -
#define DEBUG(string) WRITE(L"string") wouldn't work for the ones which have format specifiers.

Comment: convert at code level?

Comment: You mean convert every statement? There are thousands of them.
If you meant something else, can you give an example.

Comment: And why can't you change DEBUG macro?

Comment: Can you do a find and replace on your code to an intermediate function PrintDebugStr and then write this function to accept format specifiers and call WRITE(L"generated string")

Comment: This is not really an AD. I have toolkit that has something for that purpose. Drop a line if you are really interested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking at : `#define DEBUG(str,...) WRITE(str,__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like the gnu function

```
int asprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, ...);
```

that is a function that returns an allocated string of sufficiently large size in `*strp` that holds your printed string. Supposing that your `WRITE` and `DEBUG` macros are only used in places where they are used as statements and not inside expressions, you could then do

```
#define DEBUG(...)              \
do {                            \
  char* strp = 0;               \
  asprintf(&strp, __VA_ARG__);  \
  WRITE(strp);                  \
  free(strp);                   \
} while(0)
```

If your platform doesn't have `asprintf`, you probably can come up with an implementation of it that uses `snprintf` and enlarges the string to be returned as needed.